# debootstrap leaves installation without apt

Tags: apt, debootstrap

Following the [ZFSonLinux guide on how to install Ubuntu 16.04 with a ZFS root file system](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-Root-on-ZFS) I've gotten up to the point of bootstrapping the new Ubuntu install which is where I meet resistence. Running the sequence of commands that are:

```
# chmod 1777 /mnt/var/tmp
# debootstrap xenial /mnt
# mount --rbind /dev  /mnt/dev
# mount --rbind /proc /mnt/proc
# mount --rbind /sys  /mnt/sys
# chroot /mnt /bin/bash --login
```

I'm then left with a chroot without apt:

```
# apt-get
bash: apt-get: command not found
```

Even specifying that `apt` should be included does not help. Though one may observe how apt is listed among one of the packages that are downloaded, but not extracted:

```
debootstrap --include=apt --arch=amd64 xenial /mnt http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
...
I: Checking component main on http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu...
I: Validating adduser 3.113+nmu3ubuntu4
I: Validating apt 1.2.10ubuntu1
I: Validating apt-utils 1.2.10ubuntu1
I: Validating base-files 9.4ubuntu4
...
I: Extracting adduser...
I: Extracting base-files...
...
```

Does anyone know how this would happen? I've never had a debootsrap not include apt before.

Comment: Nope, command not found. `find / -iname apt`  only comes up with the `/etc/apt` I made myself and `/var/cache/apt`, `/var/lib/apt` which I've not created.

Comment: Download `apt` from the official website [apt_1.2.15ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/apt/download) then install it through `dpkg`

Comment: Unfortunately its not that simple. Apt in turn depends on a whole bunch of packages which aren't installed either such as `libc6`.

Comment: Remove the `--include=apt`  from the `debootstap` option , it is not required because `apt` is available on the `main` repo ( it can be the cause of the problem , i don't know)

Comment: I've tried both with and without the include flag. Perhaps that was not clear enough from the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My sin seems to have been bindmounting `/dev`, `/proc` and `/sys` into the chroot before running debootstrap. I can't be entirely sure since I also rebooted the machine at one point as I was unable to unmount the rbinds, but the debug output of debootstrap indicated that this was the problem.

Comment: your question & answer just saved me several hours! thanks a lot!

Comment: NOTE: this is answer is still valid for `ubuntu 20.04`.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was not running the `--second-stage` inside the chroot folder `mnt`.

```
sudo chroot mnt /bin/bash -c "/debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage"
```

With this stage the packages and everything elese were installed.